# How can I set a wordpress(windows hosting) page/section to use a subdomain?

Tags: php, wordpress, iis, web-config, subdomain

I have been researching through the web a lot and found nothing that fits to my specific situation.(Actually, nothing that works so far). 
Let's say I have a wordpress site on domain.com. I have a section/page I am going to call testpage. I need it set to use testpage.domain.com. 
As title says, this is a windows hosting.
I tried following:
**1)** I added the following rule to web.config:

```
<rule name="Rewrite sub-domain to dir" enabled="true">
    <match url="^(.*)$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^testpage\.domain\.co\.uk$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="testpage/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

**2)** 
I Created the subdomain and set it to /testpage
Then in testpage I put index.php with the following code:

```
<?php
/**
* Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn’t do anything, but loads
* wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
*
* @package WordPress
*/

/**
* Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
*
* @var bool
*/

$_GET[‘page_id’]=4323;

define(‘WP_USE_THEMES’, true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require(‘../wp-blog-header.php’);
```

I took the id from wordpress.

I am not a coder and while I kinda understand a bit of code in both cases, I am far from an expert and I can't say for sure there are no errors there. But thing is none of those methods worked for me.
**Method 1** will load testpage.domain.com/testpage, instead of just testpage.domain.com
**Method 2** will kinda work but just loads the home, instead of the page whose ID I put in the code.

I thank a lot in advance to anyone who takes a look at this.

Answer (score 0):

My friend, I would recommend to switch to Linux hosting where you can play with proper redirects.

Comment: Yeah, sadly it is not my choice in this case.